# Comparar si una cadena se lee igual alreves (palindromo) C

Tags: c

**Buenas, se me pide la siguiente consigna:**
Dada una cadena de caracteres, hacer una función que determine si dicha cadena es palíndromo (se lee de igual forma de adelante para atrás como viceversa) o no. La función recibe como parámetro la cadena y retorna 1 o 0 según sea la respuesta.

Desarrollé el siguiente código pero siempre me retorna 1. Debería retornar 0 si las cadenas se leen de igual manera al revés.

```
int main()
{
    char cadena [30] = "hola julian";
    char pal [30] = "amor a roma";
}
```

```
int palindromo (char c []){

int longitud = strlen(c);
int x=longitud;
int i=0;
int flag=0;

    while(i<longitud && flag==0){
        if(c[i]==c[x]){
            flag=0;
        }else {
            flag=1;
        }
        i++;
        x--;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Si a la función le paso por parámetro la cadena **pal** debería retornar 0 la función pero aun así retorna 1. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 5):

Dos cuestiones:

Primero, el comportamiento es el opuesto al que dices: la función devolverá 0 si la palabra es un palíndromo (c[i]==c[x] para todas las iteraciones).

En todo caso hay un bug: los caracteres de la cadena van de la posición 0 a la posición *longitud - 1*, así que x deberías inicializarlo a *longitud - 1*.

Como optimización, *i < longitud* se puede cambiar a *i < x*.

Y por último, hay que acostumbrarse a depurar el programa. Bien con un depurador del IDE, o bien metiendo un *printf* en el bucle,

```
printf("Comparando posición %d (%c) con %d (%c)\n", i, c[i], x, c[x]);
```

te habría dado bastante información de qué hacía tu programa.

Comment: +10 `hay que acostumbrarse a depurar el programa`.

Answer (score 2):

> Si a la función le paso por parámetro la cadena **pal** debería retornar 0 la función pero aun así retorna 1. ¿Alguna idea?

Varias, tu algoritmo es erróneo.

- Tu bucle no finaliza al detectar un caso erróneo, te detectaría palíndromo en textos que sin ser palíndromo, tuviesen letras repetidas en el centro (Como "*Baal*") o en todos los textos con letras impares (Como "*Boniato*").
- Bueno, eso sucedería si parases de hacer comprobaciones en el centro del texto, pero es que compruebas el texto completo, desde `i=0` a `i=longitud`.
- Además, tienes el resultado girado (como señala [SJuan76](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/382452/2742)).

Mi consejo es que descartes tu algoritmo por completo y siguas los siguientes consejos:

1. Modifica tu  función para recibir un rango de valores (dos punteros), esto hará que la función sea más flexible.
2. Por convención, se considera que un bucle `while` se debe usar cuando se desconoce el número de iteraciones, como no es tu caso usa un bucle `for`.
3. No compruebes el texto entero, sólo te interesa la mitad.
4. Finaliza el bucle si detectas un caso negativo, así ahorras ciclos de proceso y evitas  errores.
5. No uses banderas (*flags*), además de ser innecesarias en este caso, son muy propensas a errores.

Siguiendo esos consejos, tu función podría parecerse a:

```
int palindromo (char *inicio, char *fin) {
    for (; inicio < fin; ++inicio, --fin)
        if (*inicio != *fin)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

El código anterior devolverá `0` para `palindromo(cadena, cadena + 10)` y `1` para `palindromo(pal, pal + 10)`. Al ser un rango te permite comprobar palíndromos en sub-cadenas:

```
char texto[] = "La palabra salas es un palíndromo";
printf("%d", palindromo(texto, texto + strlen(texto) - 1)); // Muestra 0
printf("%d", palindromo(texto + 11, texto + 15));           // Muestra 1
```