# Identificar si una palabra es palindroma en c++

Tags: c

muy buenas este tengo un problemita y es que estoy haciendo un código por separado para que lea las palabras que son palíndroma para mi proyecto pero me ejecuta el programa pero cuando escribo una palabra pues se cierra automáticamente inserto el código que estoy usando me ayudarían mucho si me solucionan este problemita si (si es posible que las palabras no sean ingresada una por una sino en un char y con ese char pues que enliste las palabras que son palindromas no es necesario que estén enumeradas)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string texto;
    int aux = 0, igual = 0;

    cout << "Ingrese la palabra a evaluar: ";
    getline(cin >> ws, texto);

    for(int ind = texto.length() - 1; ind >= 0; ind--) {
        if(texto[ind] == texto[aux]) {
            igual++;
        }
        aux++;
    }

    if(texto.length() == igual) {
        cout << "La palabra ingresada es palindromo!! :D" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "La palabra ingresada no es palindromo!! :D" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comparar si una cadena se lee igual alreves (palindromo) C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382447/comparar-si-una-cadena-se-lee-igual-alreves-palindromo-c)

Answer (score 0):

Tu programa funciona correctamente. El error que estás teniendo es que estás mezclando C con C++. Échale un vistazo a las librerías que estás insertando, ya que estás mezclando librerías de C++ con otras de C, además de incluir librerías que no son necesarias. He probado tu código sin realizar modificaciones y funciona perfecto.

**Actualización código**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_PALABRAS 3
#define LEN_PALABRA 100


int main() {
    string texto;
    int aux = 0, igual = 0;
    int palabras_palindromas = 0, contador_palindromas = 0;
    std::string palindromos[NUM_PALABRAS];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_PALABRAS ; i++)
    {
        aux = 0;
        igual = 0;
        cout << "Ingrese la palabra a evaluar: ";
        getline(std::cin, texto);

        for(int ind = texto.length() - 1; ind >= 0; ind--) {
            if(texto[ind] == texto[aux]) {
                igual++;
            }
            aux++;
        }

        if(texto.length() == igual) {
            cout << "La palabra ingresada es palindromo!! :D" << endl;
            palindromos[i] = texto;
            contador_palindromas++;
        } else {
            cout << "La palabra ingresada no es palindromo!! :D" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "RESULTADO DE PALABRAS PALINDROMAS:" << endl;
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= contador_palindromas ; j++)
    {
        cout << palindromos[j] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: si pero deberia salir el mensaje "La palabra ingresada es palindromo" pero no me sale sino que se cierra el programa al escribir la palabra @Londo

Comment: He probado el código y sale el mensaje que me comentas, incluido el emoji que has puesto. Prueba en cualquier compilador online de C++, quitando las cabeceras que hacen alusión a C, y verás que funciona correctamente.

Comment: este se puede hacer algo en ese codigo para que lea una cadena de caracteres y  me ponga en lista solo las que son palindromas por ejemplo: oso perro gato ala reconocer;  de ahi que despues de que se lea eso solo se impriman                                      oso, ala , reconocer (en lista)

Comment: No tengo ni idea de C++, pero ese código que te dejo en la solución (que seguramente sea una chapuza enorme) hace lo que creo que estás buscando. En este caso, tienes un límite de palabras a meter de 3, que lo puedes cambiar y pedirle al usuario que inserte el número de palabras. Después de introducir todas las palabras te muestra por pantalla aquellas que son palíndromas.

Comment: vaale bro muchas gracias por tu ayuda ^w^

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta márcala como válida para que los próximos usuarios sepan que es una solución válida ;)