# Palindromo en C

Tags: c, string

soy nuevo programando en C, estoy intentando hacer un programa para que detecte si una palabra o frase es palíndroma o no, llevo lo siguiente, pero el problema que tengo es que al comparar los dos strings, osea aux(donde se guarda el string ingresado) y str2(donde se guarda el string alreves), siempre me imprime que no es palíndroma sin importar si es o no la palabra palíndroma, así que quisiera saber porque sucede esto o como pudiera arreglarlo, gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){ 

char str[50], str2[50], aux[50]; 

printf("Ingrese un string para verificar si es palindroma\n");
fgets(str, 50, stdin);

strcpy(aux,str);
strcpy(str2,strrev(str)); 

if(strcmp(aux,str2) == 0){
   printf("La palabra es palindromo\n");
}else{
 printf("La palabra NO es palindromo\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Comparar si una cadena se lee igual alreves (palindromo) C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382447/comparar-si-una-cadena-se-lee-igual-alreves-palindromo-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque tengo mi C un poco oxidado, creo que el problema lo tienes en `strcpy(str2,strrev(str));`, la función strrev creo recordar no devuelve un resultado como tal, sino que modifica el valor de str (en este caso).

Si ejecutas esta sentencia de manera aislada y luego haces la comprobación debería funcionar.

Además, al introducir la palabra y pulsar enter se añade un salto de línea que al comparar siempre te dirá que no son iguales.

Como anécdota, la función para el reverse no está presente en entorno linux, por lo que podrías evitar su uso.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char str1[50], str2[50];

  printf("Ingrese un string para verificar si es palindroma\n");
  fgets(str1, 50, stdin);

  // Elimino el salto de línea al final de la cadena.
  int i;
  long int length = strlen(str1) - 1;
  if (*str1 && str1[length] == '\n') 
    str1[length] = '\0';
    
  // Hago el reverse sin usar la función porque ésta no funciona el linux / mac.
  length = strlen(str1) - 1;
  for (i=0; i<=length; i++) {
    str2[length-i] = str1[i];
  }

  if (strncmp(str2, str1, length) == 0) {
    printf("La palabra es palindromo\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("La palabra NO es palindromo\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```